# folder created has the user and group as www-data - Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, filesystems, laravel-5.5

I am trying to create a folder in the app directory but for whatever reason the there is a lock symbol in the folder icon and the user and it's group is www-data.

```
$folder_path = app_path('core/'.$module);
if (!file_exists($folder_path)) {
    File::makeDirectory($folder_path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = false, $force = false);
    //mkdir($folder_path, 0777);

    exit;
} else {
    //
}
```

When I was trying to create the folder there was a permission denied error so I did `chmod -R 777 app/core/` after this when I try to create the user associated to it is www-data.

Why is it www-data and not my username and why is there a lock symbol?

NOTE: Using nginx web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As default, `nginx` and `php-fpm` will run as user `www-data`. You can check in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and `/etc/php/{version}/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

[See here](https://gist.github.com/fyrebase/62262b1ff33a6aaf5a54) if you want to config your web app run as `your username`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will try this and get back to you.